# Run python script remotely using screen

Tags: python-2.7, remote-access, argparse, gnu-screen, baud-rate

I am using intel upboard as remote machine and MacBook (using Ubuntu Linux) as my local machine.

I have python script A.py on local machine which has some variables (lets say a and b). I want to pass the values of the variables to remote file lets say B.py which is on the remote machine (intel upboard).

Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

I am using the following line of code to accomplish this, but its neither carrying the values of the variables neither its doing anything after getting into upboard.

File A.py on MacBook contains the following line of code

```
os.system('screen /dev/ttyUSB0 baudrate\'python B.py {} {}\''.format(x,y))
```

Comment: Why the `argparse` tag?

Comment: If argparse is also an option??